# Does “opacity:0” prevent an image from loading?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, opacity, microsoft-edge

Does using `opacity:0` not load the images or does it still load the content on browsers (especially Edge and IE 11)?

Comment: It does. CSS is for styling things.

Answer (score 1):

display: none load the element but keep it as hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The images are loaded, display:none will not display the element in the browser.  It is not the same as setting visibility:hidden there are subtle differences between the two settings.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, my question is: Does opacity:0 not load the images or does it still load the content on browsers

Comment: The content is still loaded just not displayed.